# Unable to upload image through form?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

Here's my HTML:

```
                            <label for="attachement1">Attach a file: <small style="color:#999;">(type: zip/rar and below 10mb)</small></label>

                            <input type="file" name="file1"/><br/>
                             <label for="snapshot">Snapshot / Thumbnail:</label>

                            <input type="file" name="thumbnail" required/><br/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" value="Publish" />
```

Here is the code in my controller file (for the update function):

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
      $this->validate($request, [

      'thumbnail' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:800',

      'file1' => 'mimes:rar,zip|max:10000',

      ]);



      $file1=$request->file('file1');

      if(is_null($request->file('file1'))){

        $p=pages::where('id', '=', $request['id'])->first();

        $attmt1=$p->attachment;

      }

      else

      {

      $upload_dir='uploads';

    $attmt1=$file1->getClientOriginalName();

    $move=$file1->move($upload_dir, $attmt1);

      }



      if(is_null($request->file('thumbnail'))){

        $p=pages::where('id', '=', $request['id'])->first();

        $image=$p->thumbnail;

      }

      else

      {

        $img=$request->file('thumbnail');

        $upload_dir='thumbnails';

        $image=$img->getClientOriginalName();

        $move=$img->move($upload_dir, $image);

        //end thumbnail process 

      }

    $mypage->title = $request->title;
    $mypage->body = $request->body;
    //$mypage->thumbnail = $request->thumbnail;
    $mypage->slug = str_slug($request->slug, '-');
    $mypage->menu_name = $request->menu_name;
    $mypage->save();

    return redirect()->route('menupages.index')->with('message', 'Page updated successfully.');
}
```

When I try to edit an item and upload an image (.jpg format), and click submit, I get a "The thumbnail must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg, png."  I checked the database and the file was not recorded.

For some reason, it is detecting the image as some foreign image file type even though it is .jpg.

Comment: Back to basic, have you implemented the enctype = multipart/form-data in the form tag??

Comment: Yes, this is the beginning of the code: `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="savepost" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: try var_dump() to check the file type and the request posted

Comment: Error: "var_dump() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given"  I used `<?php echo var_dump(); ?>`

Comment: Save file as jpg again and try again. The file might be GIF and manually renamed to JPG

Comment: @AliSheikhpour - https://www.screencast.com/t/TLWpyW5a4Iz I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from a developer on this so I will post how we were able to solve the problem.

Here's the full revised code for the function:

Controller:

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
       $this->validate($request, [

      'thumbnail' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:300000',

      'file1' => 'mimes:rar,zip|max:10000',

      ]);



      $file1 = $request->file('file1');
      if(is_null($request->file('file1'))){

      //  $p=pages::where('id', '=', $request['id'])->first();
        $p = MenuPage::find($request['id']);
        $attmt1 = $p['attachment'];

      }

      else

      {

      $upload_dir = 'uploads';

    $attmt1 = $file1->getClientOriginalName();

    $file1->move($upload_dir, $attmt1);

      }



      if(is_null($request->file('thumbnail'))){

      //  $p=pages::where('id', '=', $request['id'])->first();
        $p = MenuPage::findOrFail($request['id']);

        $image = $p->thumbnail;

      }

      else

      {

        $img = $request->file('thumbnail');

        $upload_dir = 'thumbnails';

        $image = $img->getClientOriginalName();

        $img->move($upload_dir, $image);

        //end thumbnail process 

      }

    //$check=pages::where('id', $request['id'])

    //->update([

    //  'title' => $title,

    //  'body' =>$body, 

    //  'thumbnail' =>$thumbnail, 

   //   'slug' =>$slug, 

    //  'school' =>$school, 

   //   'attachment' =>$attmt1, 

   //   'menu_name' =>$menu_name,

   //   ]);

    $mypage = MenuPage::find($id);
    $mypage->title = $request->title;
    $mypage->body = $request->body;
   $mypage->thumbnail = $image;
    $mypage->attachment = $attmt1;
    $mypage->slug = str_slug($request->slug, '-');
    $mypage->menu_name = $request->menu_name;
    $mypage->save();

    return redirect()->route('menupages.index')->with('message', 'Page updated successfully.');
}
```

View file (the bottom part):

```
                                <label for="attachement1">Attach a file: <small style="color:#999;">(type: zip/rar and below 10mb)</small></label>

                            <input type="file" name="file1"/><br/>
                            <label for="snapshot">Snapshot / Thumbnail:</label>

                            <input type="file" name="thumbnail" required/><br/>

                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                            <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">

                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" value="Publish" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you Add enctype="multipart/form-data" on your form?

```
 <form method="post" Action= "" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 </form
```

Comment: Yes, this is the beginning of the code: `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="savepost" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to upload something, you always need to add the following code to your form.

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

If you don't do this, you can't upload something.
Did you add this to your html form?

Comment: look at my comments above.

Comment: Could you provide the full code, with the part where the submit button is pressed and the php is called?